# want to more classify about my RegEx (regular expression)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
var re = new RegExp(/\btranslate\b(\(([-+]?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)\s([-+]?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)\))/g);
```

It matches **"translate(-0.24588 125.3)"** from **"kjgjhgjkg jgjgj kjgjkg hj translate(-0.24588 125.3) jjhkjghj"** string.

Now what I have approached is shown below. I find a particular string but I want to further replace that matched string.

```
var re = new RegExp(/\btranslate\b(\(([-+]?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)\s([-+]?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)\))/g);
undefined
var string = "kjgjhgjkg jgjgj kjgjkg hj translate(-0.24588 125.3) jjhkjghj";
undefined
var firstelem = re.exec(string);
undefined
firstelem
["translate(-0.24588 125.3)", "(-0.24588 125.3)", "-0.24588", "0", ".24588", "125.3", "125", ".3"]
```

Here, **["translate(-0.24588 125.3)", "(-0.24588 125.3)", "-0.24588", "0", ".24588", "125.3", "125", ".3"]**.

I think it should be only one match and that would be
**["translate(-0.24588 125.3)"]**.

So, I actually need to replace **translate(-0.24588 125.3)** with **translate(-0.24588, 125.3)** in the **"kjgjhgjkg jgjgj kjgjkg hj translate(-0.24588 125.3) jjhkjghj"** string. How can I do this?

Any suggestions how to improve my regular expression or other parts of code are welcome.

Comment: Have a look, only one submatch is returned with [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/1g9bm1fx/1/). It is not the problem with your regex.

Comment: @stribizhev where i look dude.?

Comment: @stribizhev Hi so i actually need to replace **translate(-0.24588 125.3)** by translate(-0.24588, 125.3) in the string "kjgjhgjkg jgjgj kjgjkg hj translate(-0.24588 125.3) jjhkjghj" so how can i do this ..??

Comment: If you want to use snippets, you should also actually print things out (so "Run code snippet" shows something), otherwise it's pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a comma inside the `translate(value value)` string, you may modify your code like this:

```js
var re = /\b(translate\b(?:\((?:[-+]?(?:[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)?)))\s([-+]?(?:[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)?\))/g; 
var str = 'kjgjhgjkg jgjgj kjgjkg hj translate(-0.24588 125.3) jjhkjghj';
var result = str.replace(re, "$1, $2");
document.write(result);
```

What I did is re-distributed the capturing groups so that there are just two of them. The first one `(translate\b(?:\((?:[-+]?(?:[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)?)))` matches `translate(value`, and the second one - `([-+]?(?:[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)?\))` - matches `value)`.

Comment: nice one One thing i learned that making Regular expression is not the only thing you need to make it that how it will help you to make your solution possible Thanx @stribizhev